# How do I ALTER all columns of one type to another type?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, alter-table

Let's say I want to change the data type of all columns of one type to another. How would I go about doing this, for example converting all `bigint`s to `int`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In psql, you'd run something like this which will output a bunch of commands.

```
SELECT format(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I.%I ALTER COLUMN %I SET DATA TYPE int;',
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  column_name
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE data_type = 'bigint'
  AND table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
  AND lower(table_schema) <> 'information_schema'
  AND is_updatable = 'YES';
```

You can spot check them and if you're good to go execute them with `\gexec`.

Comment: You can also wrap a similar query up in a PL/PgSQL `DO` block with `EXECUTE`.

Comment: @CraigRinger feel free to add it in too, Thanks for the additions, I almost feel like asking another question why `lower(table_schema)` rather than just `table_schema`, but I'm 100% sure you did it right and I made the mistake, or what other `pg_%` schemas there are